# WPF - Style bound to a property via ValueConverter not updating correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a Style converter defined as below:

```
public class StyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is MyStatus && targetType == typeof(Style))
        {
            var status = (MyStatus)value;
            switch (status)
            {
                case MyStatus.First:
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("firstStyle");
                case MyStatus.Second:
                    return Application.Current.FindResource("secondStyle");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In `App.xaml` I've got some styles defined as below:

```
    <Style x:Key="firstStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="secondStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
    </Style>
```

And in `Window.xaml`:

```
    <MyApp:StyleConverter x:Key="StyleConverter" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyApp:Item}">
        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder"
                Style="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}">
             <!-- some content here -->
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItems" />
```

`Item`:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private MyStatus status;
    public MyStatus Status {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding `Item` instances to `ObservableCollection<Item>` collection which is bound to `MyItems` (and `MyStatus` is a simple enum)
My problem is that the style is applied properly only for the first time and is not changing after I change the `Status` property of `Item`

Comment: I think you're looking for [`VisualStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use it in my case?

Comment: Maybe you should call `FindResource("secondStyle");` instead of `FindResource("secordStyle");`?

Comment: that was just a typo I did simplifying my example. corrected

Comment: Did you check that Status was really changed (by putting a breakpoint for example)

Comment: O_o I swear I did check that earlier but you're right - the Status wasn't even changing; I was changing it directly instead of using setter :| Thank you @BenoitCatherinet, everything's working now :)